# Google Apps Script: What does "Deserialization of continuation failed" mean?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a Google Apps Script to do some fancy computation in a Google Spreadsheet.

The script reads values from two columns in the sheet, and writes its output to a third column.

When the script is invoked, I call `var someVar = Browser.inputBox("prompt");` 3 times in order to get -- from the user -- the column names of the 2 *input* and 1 *output* columns.

For example, if a user wants the script to read from columns A and B and write to column C, he/she should specify the letters 'A', 'B', and 'C', in the specified order, in the 3 input boxes that pop up.

The script executed successfully a number of times. Lately, after the first `Browser.inputBox` call (meaning after filling some value in the input box, and pressing OK), a "Deserialization of continuation failed" error occurs (it is shown in a red, toast-like message box at the top of the page), and the script stops executing (meaning the 2 remaining input boxes do not appear).

I googled for "Deserialization of continuation failed", I got literally 2 results. Both of them are useless. Does anyone know what is this error message supposed to mean, and how to fix it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Browser.inputBox` or other script pausing operations are used (eg. the debugger) and are waiting end user interaction, the script is "serialized" (fancy word for stored) as a [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

If you are able to narrow down this error in some reproducible scenario, please lot an item in the Issue Tracker. Or perhaps look through other reported with continuation - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=continuation

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It seems it is random. Now it doesn't throw the error anymore. If it happens again I will try to pin down its scenario.

Comment: Sounds good. If it is seems random see if there are some other factors like the number of popups or time of day that might affect it. It would be good if you close out this question and re-open an Issue Tracker item when you know more. We appreciate you trying to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Why do you want me to close the question? I don't have enough reputation to vote for closing it, anyway. I can only delete it, since I am its author, but I guess it is better to keep it since it might be helpful for others who face the same problem.