# Persistent "IO error when deserializing continuation" error

Tags: io, runtime-error

I realize almost the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002566/io-error-when-deserializing-continuation) was asked, but it was over a year and a half ago and didn't really have an answer.  I need a solution and soon, so I am asking again.  Here is my story:

I use Google Apps Script to teach coding to middle school students.  We write and run very basic code.  [This website](https://sites.google.com/site/ltcgas/) shows the types of things we do. The instructions we follow are commented out within the code itself.

Everything had been working fine, then just last night I started getting
the error "IO error when deserializing continuation" when running code.  It
appears to happen randomly, as I could run the exact same code multiple
times and sometimes have the error appear, and sometimes not.  This will
happen even on an extremely basic piece of code.  Here is an example of code that I can't run more than 2 or 3 times without getting the error (I included the code for the menu I use to initiate the script):

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "variables", functionName: "variables"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Learn to Code with Google Apps Script", menuEntries);
}
function variables() {
  var input;
  var name=Browser.inputBox('What is your name?');
  Browser.msgBox('Your name is...');
  Browser.msgBox(name);
}
```

I am presenting the coding curriculum from the website above on Friday to a
group of educators, and if this error persists, it will ruin my
presentation.

Please help!!

Comment: Well, the problem has disappeared almost as mysteriously as it appeared, which seems to be what happened [a year and a half ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002566/io-error-when-deserializing-continuation).  Since no code ever changed, and it went from working, to not working, to working again, I don't think I can say the problem was solved, since if it happens again the only thing to do would be to wait for it to go away again.  If someone from Google can attribute it to server updates or something like that, it would at least explain it a little.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this sort of thing can happen under circumstances where your script's execution is "paused" by modal UI interaction (in this case, your msgBox) as noted [in this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283246/google-apps-script-what-does-deserialization-of-continuation-failed-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Why is Browser.msgbox the common denominator? Why is "the problem disappeared on its own, as suddenly as it appeared" a common refrain? Could this issue have something to do with the time delay (latency) of the system (PC and Internet) at the time of script execution?

I experienced this problem last night for the first time with a well-proven script. As it happened, this was also the first time I was running FreeFileSync in the background, syncing my two NAS drives. On a hunch, I paused the sync process, and the script problem behavior improved enough to finish the task (though still not without occasional errors).

Time delay (latency) changes due to system load variations (with time of day, background processes, etc.), could explain such apparently random behavior. I have not seen this issue raised. If so, the problem might be fixable on Google's end, by increasing a "timeout" variable. (Other reported "solutions" may be red herrings, successful due to temporarily-reduced system latency.)